# how to split a string and assign it to new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this value **10-X-002** in a column and I want to extract only the **X-002** to be in a new column.

So far what I have tried was this:

```
mask = df["eq_id"].str.count('-').gt(0)
splitted = df["eq_id"].str.split("-")
df.loc[mask, "eg_number"] = splitted[mask].str[-1]
```

but the script resulted only the **002** is in the new column, what should I do to get **X-002** value in the new column?

Thankyou.

Comment: You should just try to split only once. change it to `splitted = df["eq_id"].str.split("-",1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add first + and '-' with last element

```
mask = df["eq_id"].str.count('-').gt(0)
splitted = df["eq_id"].str.split("-")
df.loc[mask, "eg_number"] = splitted[mask].str[1]+'-' +splitted[mask].str[-1]
```

[image]

Comment: if you can plz upvote my answer @nomnom3214

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to only change one line in your code which is totally fine.

change this `splitted = df["eq_id"].str.split("-")`

into this `splitted = df["eq_id"].str.split("-", 1)`

which means you want only one split based on `'-'` starting from the left.

Leave the rest of your code unchanged, it should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
df["eq_id"].replace('10-','')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index location of the string, then you can do this:

```
mask = df["eq_id"].split('-')[1]+'-'+df["eq_id"].split('-')[-1]
df.loc[mask, "eg_number"] = mask
```

Split them by '-' sign and recombine those back, and just assign back to that specific column